# SSH local STDOUT to file on remote server

Tags: ssh, scp, stdout

I need to copy output from *local* command to remote server
f.e:

```
user@localhost$ ls | scp - user@remotehost:/user/remotefile
```

got an error:
-: No such file or directory

sorry, but a cannot identify error. any idea?

Comment: How about using `netcat`/`nc`? Can you open a port on the remote host?

Comment: it's not a problem to use nc :) but i need to know to to solve this task via scp

Answer (score 4):

The `scp`, *Secure CoPy using ssh* should be used to transfer files.
For stream saving, `ssh` will do the job.
To save an output to a remote file via ssh, simply use ssh and redirection.

```
$ ls | ssh user@remotehost 'cat > /user/remotefile'
```

Can be used to unpack selected file from an compressed archive:

```
$ unrar p -inul rarFile.rar inPath/afile.txt | ssh user@host 'cat > /destination/file.txt'
```